# I am trying to override model class "Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer" but nor work?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, layered-navigation

I am trying to override "**Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer**" class but not work.

i) **config.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Surtikart_Underprice>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Surtikart_Underprice>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <underprice>
        <class>Surtikart_Underprice_Helper</class>
      </underprice>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <underprice>
        <class>Surtikart_Underprice_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>underprice_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </underprice>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>Surtikart_Underprice_Model_Catalog_Layer</layer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

ii) class file

```
<?php
class Surtikart_Underprice_Model_Catalog_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
{
     public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()==290){
        $startprice=0;
            $endprice=499;
             $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $startprice))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $endprice));

        }else{
            if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }



        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

What is mistake i cant able to reach..

Thanks.

Comment: please check log files, is there any error ?

Comment: here no error...

Comment: Same thing working for me. Can you debug at `getProductCollection()` function. `public function getProductCollection(){ echo "test"; exit; ...... `

Comment: yes, i am check this but no one break found in function. its directly execute.